# Comparing Multivariate Means

Tags: t-test, multivariate-analysis, circular-statistics

Apologies in advance if this is very basic; I am quite new to statistics.

I have a large set of 7 dimensional data, for two groups.

In my example, they are express relative preferences over a certain bundle of goods (for men, and for women). (Weightings of the parameters in a representative utility function, so for example X1=<2,3,1,4,5,2,7>).

As such, one could interpret them as either two sets of multivariate data, or equivalently, two sets of 7-dimensional directional unit vectors, without any loss of relevant information.

I want to see if the populations have different means.

First question, should I try to use a multivariate t test, or delve into the literature on directional statistics? (the latter seems to represent the intuition behind the data structure better)

Secondly, can you recommend R packages that might be able to do either of the above? The 'circular' statistics package, as far as I can tell, does not extend to N dimensional vectors.

Thirdly, and I'm throwing this out there more if anyone could indicate which area of literature to examine, suppose the sets of data represent ordered variables? And supposing they were paired instead of independent (say representing twin 1 and twin 2)? What would be the best topic to investigate to help answer questions such as, for example, does a skew in the 'twin 1' data towards the first few ('lower order' variables) correlate with a similar skew towards the first few in the corresponding 'twin 2' data? Or if twin 1 highly prefers 'higher order' goods twin 2 prefers 'lower order' goods? And so on.

Thanks in advance!

```
EDIT   (adding information given in comment)
```

So a little bit of context - the data arises from a simulation exercise where users are given a budget of say £10 and a menu of prices for different items. From each 'market' we assume their choice is their optimal bundle and we use a generic utility function = $U = \alpha(\ln (x_1))+\beta(\ln (x_2) +\dots$. For $k=7$ items to compute their relative weights for each item. That is, the solution can be represented by the 7D unit vector; magnitude is irrelevant. I'm trying to see if men and women differ systematically in their preferences.

Comment: Means of *what*? I do not (yet) understand how it would make sense to average these relative preference data. Although they can indeed be *represented* as 7D vectors, what they *are* is a set of permutations--orderings of seven things. What would the meaning of an "average" permutation be in your application?

Comment: I suppose that's why the directional interpretation is more intuitive; the mean direction, in that case. So for example if you had:

A = <1,2,3>
B = <3,1,2>
C = <2,3,1>

the mean direction would be:

mu = <2,2,2>

Comment: Sorry - to make that more clear, I should state that I'm only interested in the relative ratio between any two members of the vector; i.e. in the above example A,B and C could be reduced to their unit vectors (a monotonic transformation) and the relevant information is retained. The mean direction should really be <(1/3)^0.5,(1/3)^0.5,(1/3)^0.5>

Comment: You should post more of your applied context, then it could be an interesting question! Means of permutations certainly can be defined, one need first a metric on permutations, and then can use some Frechet mean (see the wikipedia article).  Then we could look for ideas in Perci Diaconis book on group representation theory in probability and statistics.  But first, we need much more context!

Comment: Ah cool! Sounds like there are some useful paths to explore. So little bit of context - the data arises from a simulation exercise where users are given a budget of say £10 and a menu of prices for different items.

From each 'market' we assume their choice is their optimal bundle and we use a generic utility function = U = alpha(ln(x_1))+beta(ln(x_2)...etc. for k=7 items to compute their relative weights for each item. That is, the solution can be represented by the 7D unit vector; magnitude is irrelevant.

I'm trying to see if men and women differ systematically in their preferences.

Answer (score 2):

There are a class of statistics based on interpoint distances that can be used to test for differences in multivariate distributions. These tests can be used to measure differences in multivariate means, but in general will also be sensitive to other other aspects of the distributions (scale, etc.). These tests are nonparametric, and have excellant power, approaching or exceeding the power of parametric alternatives. The only catch is that p-values must be obtained using permutation.

R functions can be found in the 'energy' and 'cramer' packages. Matlab code can be found [here](http://www.subcortex.net/research/code/testing-for-differences-in-multidimensional-distributions).

There is a pretty good description on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance), and an excellant review is:

G. J. Szekely and M. L. Rizzo (2013). Energy statistics: statistics based on distances. Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference Volume 143, Issue 8, August 2013, pp. 1249-1272.